# Clear a letter of Page

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a page I want to erase a letter from the "page".

My page has 100 "&" and I need to delete all & with javascript.
My code examples:

```
hl=fa&amp;amp;ct=clnk&amp
```

How would I remove the character?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit [help] to see what and how to ask. As it stands now, your question is off-topic due to lack of example code. We are not elance.com - please show effort

Comment: Do you need to remove `&amp;` or `amp;` or  `&amp;amp;` Are these in links on the page? i.e. the hrefs

Comment: i need send this code to new page and i use get form .

Comment: That is too little information. Please write an example with proper "expected output" and "actual output" - is the code in a link or a form action? are you sure you need to change it on the client - looks more like a server encoding issue  - Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Are these ampersands on document.write? Or are they contained in some kind of a div?

Comment: i have one bottom for send source page with get to my site.

Comment: and i send this source my page not recieve

Comment: Can be more precise than bottom? Is it a div? How about sharing a snippet of that code here?

Comment: `javascript:var matn= document.getElementById("rso").innerHTMLvar title =document.getElementById("lst-ib").value ;var address="http://thisismysite.com/post/index.php?title=";var address2 = "matn=";var c = address + title + "&" +  address2 + "" + matn;window.open(c, "postsaz", "width=250, height=80")`

Comment: this is one botton in bookmark

Comment: and afrer click send source to my site

Comment: So you want the get references on your url to disappear. Which means if your URL is `www.example.com/e?a=2&b=7&c=9` 
You want
`www.example.com/e`
Is this what you mean?

Comment: i send source with get and example `www.example.com/e?a=2&b=7&c=9` and becuase source have & dont send ...

Comment: Look up url encoding.